# How to scale two displays differently and rotate one of them?

Tags: x11, gnu-screen, display, xrandr, resolution

I have two screens:

1. 4K, HDMI-0
2. 1680x1050, DVI-1

HDMI-0 is left of DVI-1. DVI-1 is rotated physically 90 degrees clockwise ( `--rotate left` will make it rotate correctly to fit the physical rotation).

**I want to scale the two displays properly and keep the rotations. How do I do this?**

Here's what I've experimented with:

#### Experiment 1:

`xrandr --output DVI-1 --rotate normal --mode 1680x1050 --scale 2x2 --panning 3360x2100+3840+0 --fb 7200x2160 --pos 3840x0 --output HDMI-0 --mode 3840x2160 --scale 1x1`

This will make both screens be side-by-side and not rotated. On DVI-1, the pointer can go past the bottom of the screen for a few pixels (~30 pixels?), however, when highlighting the screen area, the highlight only goes to just above the bottom of the screen (probably like 40 pixels).

#### Experiment 2:

`xrandr --output DVI-1 --mode 1680x1050 --rotate left --scale 2x2 --panning 2100x3360+3840+0 --fb 5940x3360 --pos 3840x0 --output HDMI-0 --mode 3840x2160 --scale 1x1`

This will rotate DVI-1 correctly but the scale will be wrong. It will be the original scale but the screen size for DVI-1 is doubled so when the mouse goes to the right or bottom edge of the screen, the screen will pan around the area of 2100x3360 but the view-port of the display will only display 1050x1680 of the screen. (Just like panning around the map in an RTS game).

I am using Kubuntu 18.04.

This question is similar to [Configure 3 screens/dual graphic/rotated screens Ubuntu 15.10](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267040/configure-3-screens-dual-graphic-rotated-screens-ubuntu-15-10) although that has 3 screens, and resolution problems as well.

Comment: xrandr transforms all its options in a final [homogeneous transformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Other_kinds_of_transformations) (which for 2D is a 3x3 matrix). So you could do the maths beforehand and use a final `--transform` option. I'm not sure if the total virtual screen size is correctly increased by xrandr.